# Unable to import another .js file

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

```
//email.js
module.exports = function send() { 
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'test@gmail.com',
            pass: 'password'
        }
        });

        var mailOptions = {
        from: 'test@gmail.com',
        to: 'test@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Revenue Report',
        text: "Hello"
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent Successfully' + info.response);
        }
    });
};
```

```
var mail = require('./email.js')();
                    mail.send();
```

I am trying to import function from email.js.

However, I've been getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send').

What is wrong with my code? Is there any solution to this?

Comment: From your export declaration, it looks like it should used like `let send = require('./email.js') /* no extra () */ ; send()`

Comment: It works but email wasn't being sent. However when I tried executing the email.js file by itself, it executed and email was sent. Weird

Answer (score 0):

you are exporting a `function` directly, So it doesn't wrap with any object where you should use `.send()`.

You can simply do,

```
// just import
var mail = require('./email.js');

// then call it
mail();
```

**OR**

```
// call as soon as imported
require('./email.js')();
```

---

If you want to keep the `send()` method inside an `object`, You should export it like,

```
function send() {
   // Your code
}

module.export = {
   send
}
```

Then you can import and use it like

```
var mail = require('./email.js');
mail.send();
```

Comment: The code went through but its weird because the email did not get sent to my gmail

Comment: For that, You should check your email configuration such as `SMTP Credentials`. Gmail blocks emails from untrusted hosts. Check spam folder

Comment: I have tried the code, it only works if I didnt do export and import.

Comment: When I tried running the email.js file by itself, the email sent through

Comment: I noticed that the code stopped at :transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info). It just skipped that part of the code after that.

Comment: You get any errors?

Comment: Nope, no errors

Comment: The code just skipped :transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info). It can execute, but it doesnt prompt me if theres an error or if the email has been sent or not

Comment: I was quite puzzled because when I import it, the email doesnt send. But when I run the email.js file itself, it executed and email was sent